# STM32G4 low-power mode

Tags: stm32, low-power, clock-speed, stm32cubeide

I have an issue with going into low power mode on the STM32G473.

To be able to use the low power regulator the SYSCLK must be below 2Mhz however it seems impossible to reduce the SYSCLK that low on the stm32G4. Because of the below limitations
96MHz<= PLLN <= 344Mhz 
8Mhz <= PLLR <= 150Mhz\

I have attached a picture of the clock configuration and the code used below:

```
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        HAL_SuspendTick();
        HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI); 
        HAL_ResumeTick();
```

[image: Clock configuration of the STM32G4]

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean HCLK to be 2 MHz instead of SYSCLK? Also, if you want to go into sleep mode with low clocks to conserve power, why bother keeping the PLL on, or even the HSE, in this case?

Comment: @Justme It says "system clock frequency" but I hadn't thought of just turning of all clocks. Thanks!